# Sticky topbar on scroll doesnot support for mobile ios next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-position, sticky

I am try to implement a sticky topbar for a form when user scroll down the form they will see the fixed top bar where percentage and other buttons. The problem is on mobile that functionality worked fine for androids except for ios ..here is my codes

```
const handleStickyPanel = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;

      windowHeight > 300
        ? setStickyClass(
            "fixed top-0 left-0 z-[10000] w-full right-0 shadow-lg"
          )
        : setStickyClass("relative");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Attach the scroll event listener
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleStickyPanel, { passive: true });

    // Attach the touchmove event listener for iOS
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", handleStickyPanel, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleStickyPanel);
      window.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleStickyPanel);
    };
  }, []);
```

even try to use touchmove instead of scroll for IOS

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Attach the scroll event listener
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleStickyPanel, { passive: true });

    // Attach the touchmove event listener for iOS
    window.addEventListener("touchmove", handleStickyPanel, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleStickyPanel);
      window.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleStickyPanel);
    };
  }, []);
```